# What to write in JSON file to create multiple line chart HTML

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I'm new to javascript so please forgive me. I am trying to make a line chart (with 4 lines) which get updated every hour. The information will be found in a JSON file however I am unsure how to write it. Previously I have tried to use `data.addColumn()` and `data.addRows()` but I couldn't find a way to connec that with a JSON file. Say if you were to make an example, please show the number of sales of four different items

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

        google.charts.load('current', {
        packages: ['corechart']
        }).then(function () {

        var options = {
            hAxis: {
            title: 'Time'
            },
            vAxis: {
            title: 'Sales'
            },
            title: 'Today',
            height: 600
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('dagens'));

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: 'getData.php',
            dataType: 'json',
        })

            drawChart(jsonData);

        }).done(drawChart);


        function drawChart(jsonData) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
```

In the getData.php file this is written:

```
$string = file_get_contents("sampleData.json");
echo $string;
```

I wish to use google's chart system if possible. Many thanks in advance.

Edit:
JSON file:

```
{
  cols: [{label: 'Time', type: 'number'},
         {label: 'Sales 1', type: 'number'},
         {label: 'Sales 2', type: 'number'},
     {label: 'Sales 3', type: 'number'},
     {label: 'Sales 4', type: 'number'}
  ],
  rows: [
     {c:[{v: 0}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 1}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 2}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 3}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 4}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 5}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 6}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 7}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 8}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 9}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 10}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 11}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 12}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 13}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 14}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 15}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 16}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 17}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 18}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 19}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 20}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 21}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 22}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]},
     {c:[{v: 23}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}, {v: 1000}]}
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you also post data for **jsonData**

Comment: I have added the JSON file now

Answer (score 3):

in order to create a google data table, directly from json, as follows...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

the json data must be in a very specific format, found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam).

as for the format of the data for a specific chart,
each has a specific format, the data format for line chart can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format).

the first column in the data table represents the x-axis,
it can be of any type (date, number, string, etc...).

the following columns should all be numbers,
which represent each series in the chart, or line to be drawn.

so an example of the json needed to draw a line chart,
with a date on the x-axis,
and four lines is as follows...

```
var jsonData = {
  "cols": [
    {"label": "Date", "type": "date"},
    {"label": "Sales A", "type": "number"},
    {"label": "Sales B", "type": "number"},
    {"label": "Sales C", "type": "number"},
    {"label": "Sales D", "type": "number"}
  ],
  "rows": [
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2019, 10, 1)"}, {"v": 1000}, {"v": 2000}, {"v": 3000}, {"v": 4000}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2019, 11, 1)"}, {"v": 1000}, {"v": 2000}, {"v": 3000}, {"v": 4000}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2020, 0, 1)"}, {"v": 1000}, {"v": 2000}, {"v": 3000}, {"v": 4000}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2020, 1, 1)"}, {"v": 1000}, {"v": 2000}, {"v": 3000}, {"v": 4000}]}
  ]
};
```

---

when using ajax to get the json data,
do not use --> `async: false` -- this option has been deprecated.

instead use the `done` promise method, which will have the data as an argument.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "getData.php",
  dataType: "json",
}).done(function (jsonData) {  // <-- json data argument
});
```

---

see following working snippet,
here, I use the `fail` promise method to hard-code the data,
since your php page cannot be reached from this site.
on your server, it should work without the fail method...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Sales'
    },
    title: 'Today',
    height: 600
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('today'));

  $.ajax({
    url: 'getData.php',
    dataType: 'json',
  }).fail(function () {

    var jsonData = {
      "cols": [
        {"label": "Date", "type": "date"},
        {"label": "Sales A", "type": "number"},
        {"label": "Sales B", "type": "number"},
        {"label": "Sales C", "type": "number"},
        {"label": "Sales D", "type": "number"}
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2019, 10, 1)"}, {"v": 1000}, {"v": 2000}, {"v": 3000}, {"v": 4000}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2019, 11, 1)"}, {"v": 1000}, {"v": 2000}, {"v": 3000}, {"v": 4000}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2020, 0, 1)"}, {"v": 1000}, {"v": 2000}, {"v": 3000}, {"v": 4000}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2020, 1, 1)"}, {"v": 1000}, {"v": 2000}, {"v": 3000}, {"v": 4000}]}
      ]
    };

    drawChart(jsonData);

  }).done(drawChart);


  function drawChart(jsonData) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="today"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

there is a problem with the ajax call.
change from...

```
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: 'getData.php',
        dataType: 'json',
    })

        drawChart(jsonData);

    }).done(drawChart);
```

change to...

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getData.php',
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(drawChart);
```

also, it appears you're missing the closing bracket to the load statement promise.
try this code...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Sales'
    },
    title: 'Today',
    height: 600
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('dagens'));

  $.ajax({
    url: 'getData.php',
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(drawChart);


  function drawChart(jsonData) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. However, I am still unsure about one thing. What you have written as the fail function, is this only going to display if my the JSON file fails to be read? I am still unable to retrieve any data from the JSON file and I believe I have written it correctly.

Comment: Alright, edited so my current version is displayed. Edit: Also, your example showed me how to check the values at specific dates. I wish to see the graph of sales every hour.

Comment: as for hours, you can use numbers as in your example, or you can add hours to the dates in my example --> `"Date(2020, 0, 1, 1)"` -- or you can even use another type --> `"timeofday"` -- which is an array with 3 numbers for hour, minute, second --> `[1, 0, 0]`

Comment: It still doesn't work. I don't know if it matters but I am trying to run the code in my web browser and also from an http-server. All the files are currently located on my desktop.

Comment: Well, seems like there are two errors. "Access to XMLHttpRequest at file:///C:/.../getData.php from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." AND "GET file:///C:/.../getData.php net::ERR_FAILED"

Comment: yes, the json or php file should be somewhere on the http server

Comment: if you place the json file on the server, you can put the path to the json directly in the ajax call and skip the php

Comment: I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Do you mean I replace "getData.php" with "sampleData.json"?

Comment: Alright so when I visit my site on the server (have replaced php with json) I now get no errors. The errors show on the version without the server if you understand what I am saying (douple pressing on html file on desktop). Still no chart on the server

Comment: is the json file in the same folder as the html page and chart code? if not, you need to add the path to the json file, along with the name --> `"/path/to/json/sampleData.json"`

Comment: I have tried with the path. All files are located on my desktop (json, html and php)