# Google Charts - DataTable Issue with API Request and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, google-visualization

I am struggling mightily with what should be a simple AJAX call to an API that renders back DataTable formatted data ([Google Visualization API Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)) for insertion into a Google Chart. The data is successfully received via the AJAX call and I can alert the response to the browser with no issue. However, when I pass in the same exact variable `chartData` - I'm met with an error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()

I've placed the code I'm using below; any assistance would be significantly appreciated.

**FRONT END [charts-testing.php]**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var chartData = $.ajax({
                    url: "includes/processing/process_chart_data.php",
                    async: false, 
                }).responseText;

                alert(chartData);
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(chartData);
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**BACK END [process-chart-data.php]**

```
<?php
include_once '../classes/clsAPI.php';
$objAPI = new clsAPI();

$api = [redacted]
$chartData = $objAPI->getDataTable($api);

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo $chartData;
?>
```

**RESPONSE FROM process-chart-data.php**

```
{cols:[{id:'AgeRange',label:'Age Range',type:'string'},{id:'MemberCount',label:'Member Count',type:'number'}],rows:[{c:[{v:'18-34'},{v:200}]},{c:[{v:'35-44'},{v:200}]},{c:[{v:'45-54'},{v:400}]},{c:[{v:'55-64'},{v:500}]},{c:[{v:'65-74'},{v:600}]}]}
```

**REQUEST HEADERS**

```
GET /includes/processing/process_chart_data.php HTTP/1.1
Host: local.site.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://local.site.com/charts-testing.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8
```

**RESPONSE HEADERS**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2020 07:08:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.2.10 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2o DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 247
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
```

It should also be noted that by replacing `chartData` with the exact response from the API (no formatting), it renders the chart without error.

***EDIT***

To illustrate the response from the API call working if manually injected into the Visualization call, see below. This successfully displays the chart and is identical to the value of var `chartData`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                var chartData = $.ajax({
                    url: "includes/processing/process_chart_data.php",
                    async: false, 
                }).responseText;

                alert(chartData);
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({cols:[{id:"AgeRange",label:"Age Range",type:"string"},{id:"MemberCount",label:"Member Count",type:"number"}],rows:[{c:[{v:"18-34"},{v:200}]},{c:[{v:"35-44"},{v:200}]},{c:[{v:"45-54"},{v:400}]},{c:[{v:"55-64"},{v:500}]},{c:[{v:"65-74"},{v:600}]}]});
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you actually using `JSON.parse()` somewhere? didn't see it in the code above. If so, parsing isn't necessary, the data table will accept a json string. also, `async:false` has been deprecated, use the `done` promise method instead...

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60098050/5090771) for an example...

Comment: I've updated the charts-testing.php to mirror the example you posted, however, now I get the error message from the Charts API: Table has no columns.×

Comment: Further, `JSON.parse` appears to be natively invoked by Google Charts' JS and that is what seems to break the rendering. I am not invoking that parsing at all.

Comment: The full error from the console is as follows: 
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at gvjs_Li (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:55)
    at new gvjs_L (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:161)
    at drawChart (charts-testing.php:17)
gvjs_Li @ jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:55
gvjs_L @ jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:161
drawChart @ charts-testing.php:17
Promise.then (async)
google.v.w.H.lo @ loader.js:317
(anonymous) @ charts-testing.php:8`

Comment: hi check my answer i made changes

Answer (score 1):

it appears that Google Visualization API doing json.parse on your data response from server so

*`$objAPI->getDataTable` should output your JSON object like this*

**instead of using 'cols'  for strings and object elements name  use "cols"**

```
  cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'NEW A', type: 'string'}]
```

**use this**

```
"cols": [{"id":"A", "label": "NEW A", "type": "string"}]
```

**also  why using async:false**

take a look at this
 you should use async then call on-success `success:function(data){/*call chart foramtting*/}`

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8,
>   the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you
>   must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the
>   corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done().

or

```
$.get('includes/processing/process_chart_data.php', function (chartData) {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(chartData);
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});});
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` appears to be natively invoked by Google Charts' JS and that is what seems to break the rendering.

Comment: yes, need to properly format json by adding double quotes `"` around all keys and strings, see above...